# Dynamically inserting the input value to a jQuery Autocomplete list

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Given a straightforward jQuery Autocomplete, I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically add whatever the user has typed into the textbox as the first item that gets returned in the list.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel", "India", "Juliet", "Kilo", "Lima", "Mike", "November", "Oscar", "Papa", "Quebec", "Romeo", "Sierra", "Tango", "Uniform", "Victor", "Whiskey", "X-ray", "Yankee", "Zulu"]
    });
});
```

For instance, if the user types "Alph", the autocomplete will return:

- Alph
- Alpha

With the "Alpha" coming from the autocomplete source and the "Alph" being dynamically inserted.

I appreciate any help as I am very new to jQuery and currently surfing the learning curve.

Comment: "Alph" is already in the textbox. I am wondering why you would want that at the top of the drop-down list also?

Comment: @Web User, fair question.  For what I am trying to build, I want users to only be able to, for the most part, add from the closed set of options coming back from the auto-complete.  The exception is, if they really want to, they can add a new option (hence why it's in the drop down) but it will require a couple of extra steps and be treated differently in the auto-complete list (always at the top, different style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
            var options = ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel", "India", "Juliet", "Kilo", "Lima", "Mike", "November", "Oscar", "Papa", "Quebec", "Romeo", "Sierra", "Tango", "Uniform", "Victor", "Whiskey", "X-ray", "Yankee", "Zulu"];
            var results = [request.term];
            var regex = new RegExp(request.term, "i");
            for(var i = 0; i< options.length; i++){
                if (options[i].match(regex))
                    results.push(options[i]);
            }
            response(results);
        }       
    });
});
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much.  I still have a lot of things I want to do but I really appreciate the starting point

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
  var options = [request.term, "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel", "India", "Juliet", "Kilo", "Lima", "Mike", "November", "Oscar", "Papa", "Quebec", "Romeo", "Sierra", "Tango", "Uniform", "Victor", "Whiskey", "X-ray", "Yankee", "Zulu"];

function source_function(request, response) {
  // make a new array with the dynamic term + all of your other options
  var autoOptions = [request.term].concat[options];
/*
   Your code to prune the options
 */
  // function to pass the displayed options back to
  response(options);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: source_function 
    });
});
```

The best option overall is to use a dynamic function to specify constantly what appears in the auto complete menu.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code.  I will give it a shot and see what I can learn from it.  You got beat by SyncXsiS by a hair but infinity karma to you sir.